# Remove square bracket from pandas.series | element type lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series with square brackets. It has lists. Some list may have more than one element.
I have tried using

```
y_train.str.join(', ')
```

but it works fine for strings, not with numbers in this case
here is the sample datatype

```
40       [3]
41       [3]
42       [3]
43       [3]
44       [3]
45       [3]
46       [3]
47       [3]
48    [0, 2]
49       [3]
```

Comment: please provide the output of `y_train.to_dict()` and the expected output for clarity

Comment: The output is as below. Although the solution mentioned by daweo works fine, but i would love to know your approach and thought process. I am struggling a lot with these pity things :( ```{0: [3],
 1: [3],
 2: [3],
 3: [3],
 4: [3],
 5: [3],
 6: [3],
 7: [3],
 8: [3],
 9: [3],
 10: [3],
 11: [3],
 12: [3],
 13: [3],
 14: [3],
 15: [4],
 16: [3],
 17: [3],
 18: [3],
 19: [3],
 20: [3],
 21: [0],
 22: [3],
 23: [3],
 24: [3],
 25: [3],
 26: [3],
 27: [3],
 28: [3],
 29: [0, 1],
 30: [3],
 31: [0, 2], ```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it following way

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[[3],[0,2],[3]]})
df['col2'] = df.col.apply(lambda x:', '.join(map(str,x)))
print(df)
```

output

```
      col  col2
0     [3]     3
1  [0, 2]  0, 2
2     [3]     3
```

`lambda` is nameless function, which accept single argument x, which is list in this case, it does change all elements to `str`-s using `map` then join them using `,` .